# How would one avoid race conditions from multiple threads of a server sending data to a client? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

I was following a tutorial on youtube on building a chat program using winsock and c++. Unfortunately the tutorial never bothered to consider race conditions, and this causes many problems.

The tutorial had us open a new thread every time a new client connected to the chat server, which would handle receiving and processing data from that individual client.

```
void Server::ClientHandlerThread(int ID) //ID = the index in the SOCKET Connections array
{
Packet PacketType;
while (true)
{
    if (!serverptr->GetPacketType(ID, PacketType)) //Get packet type
        break; //If there is an issue getting the packet type, exit this loop
    if (!serverptr->ProcessPacket(ID, PacketType)) //Process packet (packet type)
        break; //If there is an issue processing the packet, exit this loop
}
std::cout << "Lost connection to client ID: " << ID << std::endl;
}
```

When the client sends a message, the thread will process it and send it by first sending packet type, then sending the size of the message/packet, and finally sending the message.

```
bool Server::SendString(int ID, std::string & _string)
{
if (!SendPacketType(ID, P_ChatMessage)) 
    return false; 
int bufferlength = _string.size(); 
if (!SendInt(ID, bufferlength)) 
    return false; 
int RetnCheck = send(Connections[ID], _string.c_str(), bufferlength, NULL); //Send string buffer
if (RetnCheck == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    return false; 
return true; 
}
```

The issue arises when two threads (Two separate clients) are synchronously trying to send a message at the same time to the same ID. (The same third client). One thread may send to the client the int packet type, so the client is now prepared to receive an int, but then the second thread sends a string. (Because the thread assumes the client is waiting for that). The client is unable to process correctly and results in the program being unusable.

How would I solve this issue?

One solution I had:
Rather than allow each thread to execute server commands on their own, they would set an input value. The main server thread would loop through all the input values from each thread and then execute the commands one by one.

However I am unsure this won't have problems of its own... If a client sends multiple messages in the time frame of a single server loop, only one of the messages will send (since the new message would over-write the previous message). Of course there are ways around this, such as arrays of input or faster loops, but it still poses a problem.

Another issue that I thought of was that a client with a lower ID would always end up having their message sent first each loop. This isn't that big of a deal but if there was a situation, say, a trivia game, where two clients entered the correct answer in the same loop then the client with the lower ID would end up saying the answer "first" every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about mutex?

Comment: Your saying the *same* client sent multiple, independent requests synchronously on the *same socket* and you launched multiple threads to manage each request? It would seem that is where your wheels are falling off the wagon. Trying to manage each *request* as a separate thread rather than each *connection* seems to be your issue. Each connection should have its own *queue* of inbound, and outbound, messages. If you absolutely had to, you could establish sequence numbers for each outbound packet, but honestly for a chat-program that would be like eradicating an ant-hill with nuclear weapons.

Comment: Hello! I must have not explained correctly. Each client only has a single thread/socket. I'll re-read my post to see where I miss-spoke.

The issue is not the same client sending requests, but two clients sending requests to the same third client synchronously.

"Each thread should have its own queue..." This would still result in the same problem though I believe? Unless you mean that the threads should all share a queue? Because the threads would still be acting synchronously with their own queues.

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP?

Comment: Sounds like a protocol issue rather than a threading issue. If multiple clients can send another client data at the same time, the underlying protocol needs to account for that. Such as "Hi, I'm a message from A" and "Hi, I'm a message from B". If it's partial messages (why are you not sending whole packets of information at a time?), the client needs to be able to stitch them back together appropriately. This is all handled on the application level.

Comment: Race condition is part of parallel programing. Using mutual exclusion allows you to ensure a data object isn't changed while on use or sense the last time. Also if this is udp packects may arrive out of order or dropped completely. TCP they can arrive out of order but Winsock takes care of that. I think attaching a sequence I'd (large number that is incremented and Rolls over) is good way to keep order, also a time stamp so the central server van order things, but trusts the client and could be falsified.

Comment: @marshalcraft I would just use sequence numbers instead of timestamps. That way it's monotonic no matter which system the message passes through. I also wouldn't write the thing to be multithreaded to be begin with, but that's just me.

Comment: @Mr.stobbe that is a good point to. One would have to way the real performance gains then consider the complexity for multithreaded. I would keep a chat log that is updated by the central server every time a message comes in. It would also have to send an update to all clients, probably through some stream, possibly udp or web socket over TCP. The client would start a web socket connection, and request a copy of the chat log which has the sequence I'd of the last message updated, then the client will update the log of all updated messages with sequence I'd greater than the logs.

Comment: From the servers side it has to handle incoming messages and update the log, send that message to all connected clients through wss or over udp, send copy of log to new connections. So maybe three threads their or even three process to isolate data. Having separate threads for each connection would help equalize the amount of work dedicated to a connection, or make coding that easier. Mutex would regulate the log book to keep coherent organization of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If all I/O is being handled through a central server, a simple (but certainly not elegant) solution is to create a barrier around the I/O mechanisms to each client. In the simplest case this can just be a mutex. Associate that barrier with each client and anytime someone wants to send that client something (a *complete* message), lock the barrier. Unlock it when the complete message is handled. That way only one client can actually send something to another client at a time. In C++11, see [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Comment: This is **not** how I personally would design a client<-server->client type protocol, but it sounds like you would need to rethink a good chunk of your protocol and application design to do it differently.